# SDL2/C++ - Executar loop a uma frequência específica

Tags: c++, emulador, sdl

Tenho um projeto de um emulador de CHIP8 que já estava parado a um bom tempo então voltei a mexer nele hoje, já consigo extrair e desenhar sprites e já implementei quase todas as instruções, porém as vezes o emulador executa muito rápido até travar, este é o meu loop:

```
void Window::run()
{

    SDL_Event e;
    while(!quit){

        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)){

            switch(e.type){

                case SDL_QUIT:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
            }

        }

        chip8->run();
            if(chip8->drawFrame){
                chip8->drawFrame = false;

                uint32_t pixels[2048];
                for (int i = 0; i < 2048; ++i) {
                    uint8_t pixel = chip8->gfx[i];
                    pixels[i] = (0x00FFFFFF * pixel) | 0xFF000000;
                }

                SDL_UpdateTexture(m_Texture, nullptr, pixels, 64 * sizeof(Uint32));

                SDL_RenderClear(m_Renderer);
                SDL_RenderCopy(m_Renderer, m_Texture, nullptr, nullptr);
                SDL_RenderPresent(m_Renderer);

            }

    }

}
```

Ao pesquisar descobri que a frequência ideal para o CHIP8 é 500Hz e para o Super CHIP8 é 1000Hz, então como eu poderia fazer isso seja utilizando o C++ puro ou com o SDL2?